# Balancing REDOX reactions in a basic solution, when no H+ ions are present

Tags: redox

I am trying to balance the following redox reaction, in basic solution. From what I have learned, to balance a redox reaction in basic solution you simply balance it as you normally would in acidic solution, then make sure the H+ ions are neutralized by adding OH- ions. In the example below, is my answer balanced in basic solution already? Or do I need to somehow cancel out the H present in H2O?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bottom equation looks balanced to me. There are the same number of atoms of each element on each side of the equation and charge is conserved. The hydrogen in the $\ce{H2O}$ is balanced by the hydrogen in the $\ce{HAsO2}$ on the other side so it looks fine.

Comment: Thank-you. So you think this would be considered balanced in basic solution?

Comment: i don't see why not. note that i'm not familiar with the chemistry shown so i can't say whether this is a feasible reaction or not but from a balancing point of view it looks fine